# Run Application at window Login Screen

Tags: c#, winlogon, gina

I have made C# winform keyboard that i need to run at windows login screen so that user can enter password to specific user account. the computer which is using this application doses not have physical kb.

i came across [GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) some say this is the solution but there are discussions that it is only supports till win XP win vista and 7 has different scheme.

any ideas?

Comment: C++ required: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx

Comment: so can we write c++ code to use Create Custom Login Experiences and launch c# exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think is this something you could write in .NET, per this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssecurity/thread/db904891-420f-4099-8d78-740af400c179). But GINA was replaced with [Credential Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There is a sample [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1287ec56-77b4-48c4-8b58-35b7295d6c2c&displaylang=en).

Comment: Can you update the link to your sample, the link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the onscreen keyboard?

http://forums.techarena.in/customize-desktop/1131979.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're using windows vista or or windows 7 it already has an on screen keyboard.  Just choose the "*Ease of Access*" icon and then check "*Type without the keyboard*"

Comment: but i need to launch my designed one

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but for those looking for a super quick and dirty way with C# to do this, and not use C++ or C:

Registry:

Modify HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\magnify.exe (Add it if you need to) and then add a String value to the key:
Debugger

Make Debugger value equal to the path to the exe you want to run. Just tested this solution with a C# application on Windows 7 and 10 and both work as expected (You must launch the Magnifier with Win+U, or use Easy of access center.

Here is the output of my registry for this key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\magnify.exe]
"Debugger"="C:\\Path\\to\\exe\\application.exe"
```